# How to include .xlsx and .docx files in Typescript compilation output?

Tags: typescript, xlsx, docx

I'm using Typescript with NodeJS for my server.

As part of the server logic, I need to manipulate .xlsx and .docx files, but they are not included in the Typescript compilation output. The .xlsx and .docx files are used as a template to create other files.

This is how my project looks like:

```
package.json
package-lock.json
ormconfig.json
tsconfig.json
/src
  /reports
    --other-.ts-files
    Router.ts
    Report.xlsx //File that I want to be included in the Typescript compilation output
    Report.docx //File that I want to be included in the Typescript compilation output
```

How can I include .xlsx and .docx files in the Typescript compilation output?
What do I need to add to the tsconfig.json file?

Comment: I just want the Typescript compiler to include them in the final output.

Comment: But, isn't Typescript able to include json files?

Comment: I don't want to import the file. I just want the file to be preserved and kept, so that later I can manipulate it with a library by using its path, but I can't because the file is not included in the Typescript compilation output.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is possibility to add additional extensions to nodejs, but this way is already deprecated

```
var fs = require('fs');

require.extensions['.txt'] = function (module, filename) {
    module.exports = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
};

var words = require("./words.txt");
```

2) You can always use file API of node to read files

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const css = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'email.css'), 'utf8')
```

3) Combining typescript and webpack it's possible to load custom file types. For example SVG files are loaded in that way in webpack + ts. Typescript requires additional typings in this case, for example (This is more common way for frontend apps):

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

4) For reading XLSX sheets three is a good library called `xlsx`